# rails console のように、ライブラリをロードした状態で irb をスタートするには？

Tags: ruby, irb

今 ruby を用いて開発しています。

#### やりたいこと

rails console のように、今現在開発しているライブラリを読み込みながら、 irb (というよりインタラクティブな repl) を起動したいと考えました。

もう少し詳細に説明すると:

- lib/ 以下の特定のファイルを require しながら irb を起動したい。 (特定のファイル指定が難しいのならば、 lib/ 以下すべて require でも問題ない)

#### 知っていること

- irb 起動時に `-I` によって、`LOAD_PATH` に指定ディレクトリを追加しながら irb を起動できる。しかしこれだけでは、手動でほしいクラスがあるファイルを require する必要があり、これを毎回毎回行うのは手間だと考えている。

#### 質問

ruby で irb のような、インタラクティブな実行環境を、今開発しているファイルたちを require した状態で立ち上げることはできますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bundlerを使ってgemにしてしまうのがいいです。コマンドラインで

```
bundle gem gem_name
```

としてひな形を作り、その中にライブラリのコードを置いてください。依存するライブラリがある場合は、gem_name.gemspecに記載します。そうすると、

```
bundle console
```

で必要なgemを読み込んだ状態でirbが起動します。

アドホックな方法としては

```
require 'irb'
require 'hoge'
require 'fuga'

IRB.start
```

というスクリプトを実行する方法もあります。

.irbrcにrequireを書くという回答がついていますがこれはあまり良くないです。カレントディレクトリの.irbrcが読まれるのはホームディレクトリの.irbrcが無い場合です。この方法で解決する場合、今後ホームディレクトリに.irbrcを作れなくなりますので、IRBの設定を変えたくなった場合、あちこちにある.irbrcに個別に設定を書いていかなければなりません。

Answer (score 0):

irbなら、カレントディレクトリに.irbrcを用意することで、起動時に自動的にロードして実行されるので、ここに必要なrequireなどを書いておくのはどうでしょう？

詳しくは、
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.4.0/library/irb.html
の「irb のカスタマイズ」などを参照してください。